# Add class and default value to MVC dropdown that isn't linked to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty sure I should be using a ViewModel here, but it seems a bit of a waste since my functionality is already there, but here's the question anwyay.

I've got a dropdown which, on postback, sends the selected value to my controller which I then use to filter my search results. This is all working fine, however I need a default value but also I want it styled using bootstrap, so I need to add the "form-control" class to it.

So here's what I've got:

```
@Html.DropDownList("filterApp", "-- Select One --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The HtmlAttributes at the end doesn't seem to be valid, but it would work if I used a @Html.DropDownListFor() instead. Since this isn't actually linked to my model at all, I can't use the DropDownListFor().

Any anyone suggest how I get around this without resorting to creating a ViewModel?

Thanks!

UPDATE: This sorted my issue, thanks for the help!

```
@Html.DropDownList("filterApp", null, "-- Select One --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose the correct overload of the [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx) method from the list and use the one which suites your requirements. For example:

```
@Html.DropDownList("filterApp", SelectListItems, "-- Select One --",
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

If you don't want your select to be associated with any property, you don't have to use the extension method at all, the HTML `select` will work for you:

```
<select name="filterApp" class="form-control">
    <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
    <!-- other options -->
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong overload for `DropDownList`. You should use this one:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(
 this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
 string name,
 IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
 string optionLabel,
 IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

Here you can find every overload:

[SelectExtensions.DropDownList Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx)